# What is the word for someone who has a good sense of direction?

Tags: word-usage

I'm looking for a word that describes the skill of someone who has a good sense of direction ( to write on a resume) or the name of someone who has a good sense of direction? ( as in knowing maps and how to navigate)

Comment: Adaptation - people with adaptability are both flexible and versatile.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but thanks.